# Component is not picking up changes to redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component which is not able to get data from my store.

```
class UserList extends PureComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = ({
            users: []
        })
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps (newProps) {
        console.log("New Props", newProps);
        this.setState({
            users: newProps
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                TEST
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({ 'editUser': editUser, 'deleteUser': deleteUser }, dispatch);
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log("State.users", state.users);
    return {
        users: state.users
    }
};

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps, mapStateToProps)(UserList);
```

I have a reducer here:

```
let originalUsers = [...state.users];
console.log("originalUsers", originalUsers);
switch(action.type) {
    case "ADD_USER":
        originalUsers.push(action.payload);
        return {users: originalUsers};
```

The reducer is getting and returning the correct data but the line in my UserList component inside mapStateToProps; when I log "stage.users" it keeps coming up at undefined and I don't understand why.

Comment: What if you just `console.log(state)`, does anything comes up in the console? Also, I think you shouldn't inject the data to the component state like this(with componentWillReceiveProps), if you're using redux, you can just dispatch an action to update the state, and get the state from the store.

Comment: logging out state just returns a function.

I am dispatching an action to update the state in another component.  Maybe I won't need componentWillReceiveProps at all, the state should be updated correctly in mapStateToProps

Comment: Oh, you mis-placed the two arguments in connect(), just switch them and it should be fine. Like `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserList)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
export default connect(mapDispatchToProps, mapStateToProps)(UserList);
```

Should be corrected as

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserList);
```

`mapStateToProps` comes as the first parameter in the in the connect function.

Comment: Ahhhh, that was it!  Silly mistake